# Second Mat image shows the result of First Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv

**Why one image result effects on other image, created with original image?**

Here is an example, in which i am facing the above problem.

```
Mat src = imread ("A.jpg");
Mat src1 = src;
Mat src2 = src;

Process (src1);
imshow ("src1_result", src1);
imshow ("src2", src2);
```

**Note:**  "src2", shows the result of src1 and **that's my question. **Why?.** Also, when i set src2 with orignal image again as shown below.

```
src2 = src;
```

Still, src2, shows the result of src1.

**Why?, Anyone have seen this issue?**

Comment: it's taken a reference if you want a copy then call `clone` to make a deep copy so it has it's own copy

Comment: Thank you. I understood now. And had fix it. but then what is the purpose of taking reference? Where can we use it?

Comment: Because copying is expensive and what if you are passing these as params to a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `src2 = src1`,  `src2` is not a clone of `src1`, but rather it just points to the same memory location containing `src1`'s pixel values. It is just the way opencv is designed to work, for optimization purposes.

You can actually check this yourself by checking both variables' `.data` pointer, that points to pixel values. In your sample code both `src1.data` and `src2.data` will be the same.

What you would be interested in is rather `src2 = src1.clone();` only then `src1` and `src2` are independent.

Comment: Yes, thanks but then What is the purpose of taking reference of an image.
like src1 = src, i am interested to see an example where taking reference helps.

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you have a function that reads in a Mat, `foo(Mat a)`, if this optimization is not done your program will copy the whole Mat back and forth whenever the function is called.

Comment: the purpose is to not copy the whole image (probably multiple MBs) all the time , to speed things up!

Answer (score 1):

all objects src1 ,scr2 , src point to the same data

in openCV if assigned Mat object like this way src1=src , src2=src
then all Mat object point to the same signal data , but with diffirent headers,

Try instead

```
Mat src1 = src.clone();
```

or

```
Mat src2;
 src.copyTo(src2);
```